# Facebook SDK 3.0: Unable to call openForPublish after the during a session state CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication

I have a problem to call the openForPublish to open up a session with a request of a publish stream and received a CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED state. I received this session state when I try to cancel in the login dialog.
When I tried to call openForPublish again during CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED state, I received an exception saying "Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.". When I checked session.isOpened I have FALSE and isClosed is TRUE.

This is my code :

```
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null) { 
        Log.w("Facebook Session", "TopicShow object is null");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.w("Facebook Session", "TopicShow Restoring Session");
            session = Session.restoreSession(activity, null, fbSessionStateCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(activity.getApplicationContext());
        } 
    }

    Session.setActiveSession(session);



    Log.w("Facebook", "Session inital state when clicked " + session.getState().name());
    Log.w("SessionState", "isOpen = " + !session.isOpened() + " isClosed = " + !session.isClosed());
    if (!session.isOpened()) {
        Log.w("Facebook", "openForRead " + session.getState().name());
        /* Prevent it from getting error if no internet. */

            OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(activity);

            request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_stream"));  
            request.setCallback(fbPublishRequestStateCallback);

            isBlock = false;

            session.openForPublish(request);     
    } 

    else if (session.isOpened()) {
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, graphUserCallback);
        request.executeAndWait();
        isBlock = true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You cannot reopen a session that's been closed. Instead, just create a new Session() or call one of the activeSession methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is one Facebook sample project in the SDK that suggest how to handle this. 
See my answer in: [Android Facebook session issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688235/android-facebook-session-issue/17675473#17675473)