# Android Facebook session issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have used following code for Facebook authentication and it is working fine, but when I have cancelled the authentication and tried to authenticate again the app crashed and the log was  Caused by: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.`
On debug I got like this

```
{Session state:CREATED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

How can I solve this issue.Please help me.Thanks in advance

```
private void askFacebbokAuthentication() {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {

            facebook = true;
            if (!hasPublishPermission()) {

                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(
                        MyActivity.this, PERMISSIONS));

            }
        } else {
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
            openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(MyActivity.this);
            if (openRequest != null) {

                openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);

                if (!hasPublishPermission()) {
                    openRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
                }
                session.openForPublish(openRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I too had same problem, but i solved with these lines. To my knowledge we cannot request a session for new permissions which is already opened.

```
Session session = new Session(this);
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("your_permissions")));
```

I hope you already added below line in `onActivityResult()`

```
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: what are the permissions ?

Comment: Thanks Aswin, but where are you adding the first three lines?

Answer (score 3):

If the Session is neither opened nor closed, I think it is better to Session.openActiveSession()

This snipped is copied-pasted from the Facebook SDK sample project SessionLoginSample, LoginUsingActivityActivity#onClickLogin()

```
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}
```

Note that Session#openActiveSession() also creates a Session under the hood, which is OK. From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/iossdk/session/#lifecycle:

> Sessions can only be opened once. When a session is closed, it cannot
>   be re-opened. Instead, a new session should be created. Typical apps
>   will only require one active session at any time. The Facebook SDK
>   provides static active session methods that take care of opening new
>   session instances.