# How can I open a com.facebook.Session to get user's facebook friends list?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing an Android app that gets user's facebook friends list.

This is my code.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param session
 * @return
 */
private Request createRequest(Session session)
{
    Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends", null);

    Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "name", "picture",
            "gender" };
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

    Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
    parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
    request.setParameters(parameters);

    return request;
}

private void requestMyFacebookFriends(Session session)
{
    Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
    friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
            List<GraphUser> friends = getResults(response);

            mLovers = filterFriendsToMeetUserGenderPref(friends);
            // Set list adapter to show available lovers or friends.
            setListAdapter(new SelectLoversAdapter(SelectLoversActivity.this, R.layout.item_select_lovers, mLovers));
        }
    });
    friendsRequest.executeAsync();
}

private List<GraphUser> getResults(Response response)
{
    GraphMultiResult multiResult = response
            .getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
    GraphObjectList<GraphObject> data = multiResult.getData();
    return data.castToListOf(GraphUser.class);
}

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() 
{
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
    {
        if(session.isOpened())
        {
            requestMyFacebookFriends(session);
        }
    }
};

private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, Session.StatusCallback statusCallback)
{
    OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity);
    openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "email"));
    openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);

    Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();

    if(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI)
    {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);

        return session;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The main method here is `requestMyFacebookFriends` but I have a problem: **I don't know how to instance a `com.facebook.Session`.

To get it, I use `openActiveSession` method, but I'm not sure if I have to do everything I do on it because I'm very very new on Facebook development.

I use `openActiveSession` in another activity to get facebook access token.

My question is: **What I have to do to open a `Session` to get user's facebook friend list?**

Comment: If you have already opened an active session in another activity, you can just call Session.getActiveSession() in your current activity and use that session (checking for null and isOpened(), of course). See the getting started guide on more about opening a session - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("q", fqlQuery);

    Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", bundle, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();

                if(graphObject != null)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String userFriendId = object.getString("uid");
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

You can use this for getting list of friends of the user.Hope this is what you required.If you don't get anything then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("your_permissions")));
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16688469/1443981) might help you.

**EDIT:**

```
public void getBirthdays(){
        Request fBdays = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                if(response.getError() == null){
                       for(GraphUser usr:users){
                           Log.d(TAG,usr.getName());
                       }
                }
            }
        });

        Bundle requestParams = fBdays.getParameters();
        requestParams.putString("fields", "name,birthday,picture");//for extra properties
        fBdays.setParameters(requestParams);
        fBdays.executeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, this code will open a facebook login pop up? I don't want that, I want to get friends list without any login, I did the login before.