# an attempt was made to open a session that has a pending request

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

i made login and signup with Facebook functionality in my app,the problem is that once user clicks log in with Facebook button and dialog appears for login if user cancel that dialog it is redirected to login and from that if it again clicks on log in with Facebook white screen appears..Log cat shows error as "an attempt was made to open a session that has a pending request" below is my code..i am confused about this error any help is appriciated

**FaceBookIntegration.java**
/**
 *
 */

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;


import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

;

/**
 * Facebook integration class ccontains login with fb and share activity
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class FacebookIntegration extends GlobalActivity implements ResponseListener {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Session session;
    private boolean share;
    private UserHistory userHistory = null;
    Preferences preferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        preferences = HWUtil.getPreferences(this);

        share = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(HWUtil.SHARE, false);
        if (share) {
            userHistory = preferences.getShareUserHistory();
            if (Validator.isNull(userHistory)) {
                finish();
            }
        }
        Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
        session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
        }
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "publish_actions", "user_actions.fitness")).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            if (share) {
                shareOnFacebook();
            } else {
                getProfileDetail(session);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Share activity records on facebook
     */
    private void shareOnFacebook() {
        if (Validator.isNotNull(userHistory)) {
            String apiUrl;
            if ("Running".equals(userHistory.getSportName())) {
                apiUrl = "fitness.runs";
            } else if ("Walking".equals(userHistory.getSportName())) {
                apiUrl = "fitness.walks";
            } else if ("Cycling".equals(userHistory.getSportName())) {
                apiUrl = "fitness.bikes";
            } else {
                apiUrl = "*:sport";
            }

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("course", com.aimdek.healthwel.network.Request.HOST_URL + "/user-history/" + userHistory.getUserId() + "/" + userHistory.getId());
            params.putBoolean("fb:explicitly_shared", true);
            /* make the API call */
            new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/" + apiUrl, params, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    if (response.getError() == null) {
                        com.aimdek.healthwel.network.Request.getRequest().sendRequest(com.aimdek.healthwel.network.Request.SHARE_USER_HISTORY, FacebookIntegration.this, FacebookIntegration.this, RequestParameterBuilder.buildMapForShareUserHistory(userHistory.getId(), FacebookIntegration.this));
                    } else {
                        finish();
                        Log.d("Facebook error", response.getError().toString());
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
            if (Validator.isNotNull(userHistory.getHistoryPictures()) && userHistory.getHistoryPictures().length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < userHistory.getHistoryPictures().length; i++) {
                    HistoryPictures pictures = userHistory.getHistoryPictures()[i];
                    String message = getString(R.string.facebook_status, HWUtil.getFullName(preferences.getUserInfo().getFirstName(), preferences.getUserInfo().getLastName()), userHistory.getSportName());
                    params.putString("message", message);
                    if (Validator.isNotNull(pictures.getPictureUrl())) {
                        params.putString("url", pictures.getPictureUrl());
                    } else {
                        params.putByteArray("picture", Base64.decode(pictures.getData(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                        // params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
                    }
                    new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/photos", params, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            if (response.getError() == null) {
                            } else {
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(int type, Object... result) {
        if (type == Request.SHARE_USER_HISTORY) {
            preferences.setShareOnFacebook(false);
            if (preferences.isShareOnGoogle()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookIntegration.this, GooglePlusIntegration.class);
                intent.putExtra(HWUtil.SHARE, true);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                preferences.setShareUserHistory(null);

            }
        } else {
            if (Validator.isNotNull(result) && result.length > 0 && Validator.isNotNull(result[0])) {
                String response = (String) result[0];
                HWUtil.loadMainActivity(response, FacebookIntegration.this);
            }
        }
        finish();
    }


    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                if (share) {
                    shareOnFacebook();
                } else {
                    getProfileDetail(session);
                }

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * get facebook profile detail
     *
     * @param session - pass facebook session
     */
    private void getProfileDetail(Session session) {
        showProgressDialog();
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (Validator.isNotNull(user)) {
                    UserInfo userInfoDto = new UserInfo();
                    String id = user.getId();
                    userInfoDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
                    userInfoDto.setLastName(user.getLastName());
                    String email = Validator.isNotNull(user.asMap().get("email")) ? user.asMap().get("email").toString() : HWUtil.BLANK;
                    if (Validator.isNotNull(email)) {
                        userInfoDto.setEmail(email);
                        String gender = Validator.isNotNull(user.asMap().get("gender")) ? user.asMap().get("gender").toString() : HWUtil.BLANK;
                        if ("male".equals(gender)) {
                            userInfoDto.setGender(1);
                        } else {
                            userInfoDto.setGender(2);
                        }
                        userInfoDto.setUniqueId(HWUtil.getDeviceId(FacebookIntegration.this));
                        userInfoDto.setMeasureUnit(HWUtil.getMeasureUnit(FacebookIntegration.this));
                        userInfoDto.setPassword(HWUtil.BLANK);
                        String imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";
                        userInfoDto.setProfilePictureUrl(imageURL);
                        Request.getRequest().sendJsonRequest(Request.UPDATE_USER, FacebookIntegration.this, FacebookIntegration.this, RequestParameterBuilder.buildJsonObjectFromUserInfo(userInfoDto));
                        dismissProgressDialog();
                    } else {
                        HWUtil.showToast(FacebookIntegration.this, getString(R.string.allow_read_email));
                        dismissProgressDialog();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

        }).executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (session != null && !session.isOpened()) {
                Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if(!isFinishing() && progressDialog==null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

    }

    /**
     * dismiss Progress Dialog.
     */
    private void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (!isFinishing() &&progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250482/facebook-login-is-not-working-in-my-android-app/37250682#37250682.This will help you out.@Hardik Mehta

Comment: thanks @CrazyAndroid.. i got d answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688235/android-facebook-session-issue/17675473#17675473